# ATG installation in silent mode

Tags: puppet, atg, devops

Is there a way to install ATG commerce platform in silent mode. I need to do this for puppet module for ATG commerce environment setup.

Comment: Are you planning to use puppet for building a development environment or to build a production environment? Are you installing your application container using puppet?

Comment: For now we are trying to setup development environment using puppet.

Comment: In the past, when using configuration management systems, I always had the Application Server (usually JBoss) as well as the ATG Framework installed manually. The configuration management system would then be used to deploy the environment specific configurations etc (essentially the ATG-Data folder). You'll need to check if the ATG CIM tool has a 'recording' and 'playback' option. I'm not aware of one.

Comment: ATG CIM has recording and playback option, and that works. I am looking for the ways to automate installation part. If we can automate it using a properties file or answer file.

Answer (score 0):

Installation consists of two parts. Running the installers, and then configuring the instances with CIM.

Running the installers involves accepting licensing terms etc., and legally should not be scripted. However, materially, all it does is expand the compressed file into the appropriate executables and module folder structure in, say, `/opt/atg/ATG/ATG10.0.3`. Run it by your legal team and/or your Oracle contact, but there is nothing *technically* stopping you from doing this yourself with your own script that copies a pre-canned folder structure from one place to another.

CIM does support silent running by running a script that you have recorded previously. See the `-record` command line parameter. Note that the recorded script will only run in an situation identical (or very similar) to when it was recorded. The options CIM presents (and the sequence they are presented in) change depending on which modules and products are installed (in step 1), and their paths.

Answer (score 0):

First time you will need to do the installation manually to generate the response file:

```
./OCPlatform11.3.2_21REL.bin -r /path/to/ocplatform.rsp
```

Then, you can use the next command to run the silent installation using the response file:

```
./OCPlatform11.3.2_21REL.bin -f /path/to/ocplatform.rsp -i silent
```

Reference:

```
Usage: OCPlatform11.3.2_21REL [-f <path_to_installer_properties_file> | -options]
            (to execute the installer)

where options include:
    -?
            show this help text
    -i [swing | console | silent]
            specify the user interface mode for the installer
    -D<name>=<value>
            specify installer properties
    -r <path_to_generate_response_file>
            Generates response file.
```